# How to display processes using memory between an interval? (in bash)

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

How can I display processes that are using memory between an given interval in terminal? For exemple: processes that are using between 50 and 100 MB of Memory.

I tried:

`ps aux | awk '{print $4}' | sort`

but this only displays the memory for every process sorted and not in an interval.

Answer (score 1):

`ps aux | awk '$6>50000 && $6<100000 {print $6}'` should work, assuming RSS is in KB.